# navigating from one html page to another take lot of time

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, pagespeed

I am building an application where I have multiple pages. When I try to navigate between pages, it takes up to 2-4 seconds to load the page. But once any page is loaded then it is working fine.
I used all the options related to fast page loading time:

- Lazy loading
- Cache reuse
- Minified

But still I am getting the same result.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Use ajax if possible.

Comment: we can't help with the information you've shared in the question... try running Audit from chrome developer tools, it will give you specifics on why are you getting slow page load times

Comment: Check scripts (JS, CSS) download time. Use minified script version if possible, also enable static compression on the server.

Comment: Thanks I will do all these things